# Proper terminology for input, parameter or variable fixing. Refinement? Projection? Fixation? Partial valuation?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, fl.formal-languages, semantics, formal-methods, finite-model-theory

I contemplate writing a paper on automating fixing some inputs/parameters to specific values in a kind of workflow/pipeline definition language/system and looking for best terminology.

English is not my native language and I am not always confident in my wording and terminology use.

Among my motivations is a) obtaining a simple specification, with less inputs b) prevent abuse of computing resources

Is word fixing appropriate? The title 'Refining XXXX specification' sounds punchier and less ambiguous than 'Fixing inputs in XXXX specification to specific values', as fixing might be understood in the sense of correction, repair etc. Or is projecting a better word?
abstracting out?

If *fixation* sound good as a term to describe result of partial replace of input?

PS Not sure is it relevant yet due to syntax restrictions of the spec language I plan resort to, in a way, conservative approximation of the original semantics that my allow for executions/parameter valuations absent in the original

Update 1. I think of *Input Parameter Reduction*

Update 2. Probably cody is right, seems like specializing good word, thought other suggestions not bad

Comment: "specializing"?

Comment: At least in the formal methods community, the term "refinement" does not coincide with your intended use. Artifact $C$ refines artifact $A$ if no user of $C$ can observe that they're not using $A$. I read your intended use as an anti-refinement because the new thing with the additional restriction in paramter space is applicable in fewer situations than the original: it breaks the contract.
@cody's suggestion looks more reasonable to me.

Comment: Improve, adapt, update, restrict, upgrade, enhance, correct, augment, amend, rectify, sharpen?

Answer (score 1):

"Fixing" inputs or parameters to specific values can be a valid approach, but it may not be the most appropriate term to use depending on the context. "Refining" a specification sounds like a good alternative, as it suggests making the specification more specific and detailed. "Projecting" a specification could also work, but it might be better suited to a situation where the goal is to create a plan or prediction based on the specification.

You could consider using a term like "constraining" to describe the process of setting inputs or parameters to specific values. This term implies that you are limiting or restricting the possible values that can be used, which aligns with your goal of preventing abuse of computing resources.